# Render with artifacts and errors (sharp teeth in the shadow area) for basic paint texture

Tags: texturing

I seem to have had some basic problem and there's a simple solution, but I can't find it and understand it. Help me understand what kind of mistake I'm making with the renderer.

After saving the file, I have a render with artifacts and errors (sharp teeth in the shadow area)

[image]

I know I made a simple mistake in setting up materials or tying textures, but I can't figure out where I'm making it.

Please, help me.

[image]

Comment: Smooth/flat is not reason

Comment: it looks like eevee render engine, can you upload the blend file so I can see if there migth be another issue if my answer did not fix it

Answer (score 0):

this looks like eevee. these things can happen in real time engines, they are called Shadow Acne. you seem to have a very pixelated shoadow map.
Look in to the shadow tab on the poperties bar to see what shadow map resolution you have (default 512px)

but they can have multiple solutions and causes, I suggest you read this article to understand more about them.

https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Shadow-Mapping

but after i watched the video you sent in it seems more to be some sort of a bug with blender itself. using a different verson migth fix the issue

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xp237RlPagg That's how I broke it.

Comment: link does not work, dont send the studio link but the normal youtube link

Comment: updated link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xp237RlPagg

Comment: can you send over the blend files so i can try it out? it seems to be a bug, probably due to the version you are using. ive used texture pain quite a lot and never had this issue, so my guess it being an eevee error

Comment: God bless Blender community and all developers! It works! This error cannot be repeated in version 2.8

Comment: you already were in 2.8, 2.8 is just in heavy developement rigth now, not the full release and so it can have many bugs an errors, so dont be frustrated there just try a newer one, stackexchange can help you every time